# How to properly store a Chinese new year cake and how long will it last?

Tags: cake, chinese-cuisine

I've received a [Chinese new year cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nian_gao), my question is how do I properly store it? Do I need to refrigerate it? Also, how long will it last assuming that I properly store it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you ate the Nian gao cake already. If you are going to eat it in less than 10 days, just leave it in the fridge, tightly sealed in a ziplock bag.  But for longer storage, say a month or so, you could wrap it in plastic wrap, then a paper towel, then inside a freezer bag.  I would also cut up the cake so it is easier to defrost when you want to cook it.  I would not eat it after about a month.  I think that the texture would be too different after that.  But best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It can be kept in the refrigerator for up to 5 days or on the counter for 1 day. Keep in mind to seal it up in a bag or container to prevent drying out. It should be divided before being frozen. You can pan-fry it without defrosting or defrost it in the refrigerator before eating it at room temperature.